# Redhat 8 console sign in desktop display options - wayland X11 classic

Tags: rhel, console, desktop-environment

[image: redhat 8 login choices]

In doing an installation of rhel-server-8.8_x86-64.iso on a Dell optiplex 7010 pc and my home pc (asrock) I see what is in the above pic.  On a Dell r640/740 server I only see the X11 choices, I do not see the `Wayland Display Server` choices.

- why do I not see the Wayland choices on my dell r640/740 servers?
- Would the presence of an Nvidia graphics card matter?
- **What is this login menu called?**
- How does it get created and populated with all those choices?
- How can one modify this menu, specifically to make it only do Classic Wayland display server?
- Can anyone provide a link to any kind of documentation on this?
- Is this specifically a `gnome` thing?

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite deceivingly hard.  It also has different ways to approach it.  The RH documentation is [surprisingly unhelpful](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/using_the_desktop_environment_in_rhel_8/index).

First to note is that I have a Debian Bookworm, not a RH8.  However, I'll try my best to transpose it to RH8, while leaving the Debian parts for anyone else to see too.

You have three ways to influence what is being loaded.

### custom.conf - enable or disable Wayland

1. On Debian it is at `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf`.  On RH8 it should be at [`/etc/gdm/custom.conf`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_the_desktop_environment_in_rhel_8/managing-user-sessions_using-the-desktop-environment-in-rhel-8)

In section `[daemon]` you can disable Wayland by adding:

`WaylandEnable=false`

### User session configuration - default session

2. Second option is to have settings adjusted in your profile at `~/.dmrc`  (see more at gnome's help pages for `[gdm][3]` or [`gdm` user session](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/session-user.html.en) :
   For example

```
[Desktop]
Session=gnome
Language=cs_CZ.UTF-8
```

### Checking the `gdm` source code - the `X-GDM-SessionRegisters`

3. This option is, I think, the answer to your question.  I found it in the [gdm-session](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/blob/main/daemon/gdm-session.c#L3348) source code.  The answer is to use the 'X-GDM-SessionRegisters' variable in your `*.desktop` files.  These desktop files correspond with the list shown.

The `X-GDM-SessionRegisters` in the desktop file takes in a `true` or `false`.  If the value is `false` the session type should not be shown.  The one you want to see should have `true` others `false`.

The files can be found at `/usr/share/xsessions/` or if you do not have Xorg installed you can use `/usr/share/wayland-sessions` for Wayland only path.

In my case I have:

```
ls /usr/share/xsessions/

gnome-classic.desktop  gnome-classic-xorg.desktop  gnome.desktop  gnome-flashback-metacity.desktop  gnome-xorg.desktop  openbox.desktop
```

I'm not sure if RH8 has the same paths.  To what I could find it seems it does.

*Edit:*

> why do I not see the Wayland choices on my dell r640/740 servers?

Hard to say without a log, but probably Wayland was not installed?

> Would the presence of an Nvidia graphics card matter?

That should not matter.

> What is this login menu called?

GDM session list

> How does it get created and populated with all those choices?

You can check the source code I have linked above.  It takes the lists of *.desktop files (a the `/usr/share/xsessions/`) and creates a list from them.

You can try it yourself and create a simple new entry there. For example (example mapped to openbox session):

This should be enough:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Nice Openbox session
Comment=Testing if this will create an openbox session
exec=/usr/bin/openbox-session
Icon=openbox
Type=Application
```

> How can one modify this menu, specifically to make it only do Classic Wayland display server?

As I have tried to explain above you can do that with `X-GDM-SessionRegisters`.  If it does not work for you, you can simply move/delete the *.desktop files.

> Can anyone provide a link to any kind of documentation on this?

The source code apparently.

> Is this specifically a gnome thing?

Well GDM is a Gnome Display Manager so that is Gnome only.  You can use different ones like KDM, lightDM, etc. if you want to.

Comment: thanks for the info; I don't have a `~/.dmrc" and while #3 is the closest to what I'm looking for as an answer, it doesn't tell me those get created to make that list of choices at login.  On one pc I somehow have those choices there at login but on subsequent RHEL installations I do not and I do not know what I did to get those there on that one pc

Comment: `Standard (wayland display server)` would link to `/usr/share/wayland-sessions/gnome.desktop` and `Classic (X11 display server)` would like to `/usr/share/xsessions/gnome-classic.desktop`  is all i've learned

Comment: Wanting to know where those menu entries are defined

Comment: @ron I think I have shown that via the source doe. Since the OP has change I'll try to add more information to deepen the understanding

Answer (score 0):

> How does it get created and populated with all those choices?

@tukan explained it very well already.
In Red Hat Linux (and its derivatives) it reads all `*.desktop` files in `/usr/share/xsessions/` and `/usr/share/wayland-sessions/` and displays the values of the `Name` parameter in the session list, that you posted above.

If exist, it uses the Name of your locale settings, e. g. in my case `Name[de]`

```
$ head /usr/share/wayland-sessions/gnome.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name[de]=Standard (Wayland Anzeige-Server)
Name[es]=Estándar (servidor gráfico Wayland)
Name[fr]=Standard (serveur affichage Wayland)
Name[it]=Standard (server grafico Wayland)
Name[ja]=スタンダード (Wayland ディスプレイサーバー)
Name[ko]=스탠다드 (Wayland 디스플레이 서버)
Name[pt_BR]=Padrão (servidor de exibição Wayland)
Name[ru]=Стандартный (дисплейный сервер Wayland)
Name[zh_CN]=标准（Wayland 显示服务器
```

> How can one modify this menu, specifically to make it only do Classic Wayland display server?

You could remove or rename the `.desktop` files, that you don't need. If only one is available, there won't even be a menue available anymore.
But I don't know, if they would be restored with some update.

But perhaps it's sufficient for you already, to define your own standard session?
See the [Red Hat Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_the_desktop_environment_in_rhel_8/managing-user-sessions_using-the-desktop-environment-in-rhel-8#proc_setting-a-default-desktop-session-for-all-users_managing-user-sessions) on how that works.

Maybe the [GDM documentation](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable) is of help too

> why do I not see the Wayland choices on my dell r640/740 servers?

Are this packages installed?

- `xorg-x11-server-Xwayland`
- `gnome-session-wayland-session`
- `gnome-classic-session`